How can I create an adapter that can adapt between two different data machine classes
A class that stores and handles access to some machine of type A:
class DataMachineA:
    def __init__(self):
        # some dummy data
        self.data = {"type": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
                     "value": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     "description": ["text1", "text2", "text2", "text3"],
                     "duration": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
        
    def get_data(self, i):
        return self.data["duration"][i], self.data["type"][i], self.data["value"][i]

A class that stores and handles access to some machine of type B:
class DataMachineB:
    def __init__(self):
        # some dummy data
        self.data = {"type": ["D", "C", "D", "C"],
                     "measurement": [10, 20, 30, 40],
                     "time": [50, 60, 70, 80]}
        
    def fetch(self, i):
        return self.data["time"][i], self.data["measurement"][i], self.data["type"][i]


Since DataMachineA and DataMachineB share the same data attribute while initializing it differently, a multiple inheritance from the two classes is going to cause one __init__ method to overwrite data initialized by the other __init__ method.
I would suggest that the Adapter class use a composition of instances of DataMachineA and DataMachineB instead:
class Adapter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = DataMachineA()
        self.b = DataMachineB()

    def retrieve(self, i):
        return (
            self.a["type"][i], self.a["duration"][i],
            self.b["type"][i], self.b["value"][i]
        )


DataMachineA and DataMachineB does not share the same data attribute.

They do in the code you posted. If they don't you should update your question with code that better represents your use case, including how adaptee is initialized and passed Adapter, as it is unclear how adaptee has access to both machines.

I need to create an adapter that can adapt between two different data machine classes, DataMachineA and DataMachineB.The adapter shall have a function retrieve(index) that returns a tuple consisting of the type, value and duration of a
measurement i.

Yes, the safest approach is through composition as demonstrated in my answer. If you prefer multiple inheritance then the base classes must not conflict with each other, which they do in the code you posted. You need to update your question with a much better representation of your actual code if you insist on multiple inheritance for some reason.
